# Fluent NHibernate: Applying attribute to all members of a property mapped via a Component

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am using Fluent NHibernate (1.2), and am working on implementing column-level encryption. I have a custom type that handles encryption, so that the domain model can have native cleartext datatypes (simple strings, ints, DateTimes, etc.), and all the encryption/decryption work is behind the scenes.

I would like to specify which properties in each domain model to encrypt via an attribute, and use a Convention to specify the custom type for these properties, so that the domain models are nice POCOs with no mention of the custom type:

```
public class EncryptedAttribute : Attribute {}

public class UserRecord {
  public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
  public virtual string Username { get; set; }
  [Encrypted]
  public virtual string EmailAddress { get; set; }
  [Encrypted]
  public virtual DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
  [Encrypted]
  public virtual PersonName LegalName { get; set; }
  // etc.
}

public class PersonName {
  public virtual string Given { get; set; }
  public virtual string Middle { get; set; }
  public virtual string Family { get; set; }
}

public class EncryptedColumnConvention
  : AttributePropertyConvention<EncryptedAttribute> {
  protected override void Apply(
    EncryptedAttribute attribute, IPropertyInstance instance)
  {
    var dbType = typeof(EncryptedColumnType<>).MakeGenericType(domainType);
    instance.CustomType(dbType);  
  }
}

public class UserRecordMap : ClassMap<UserRecord> {
  public UserRecordMap() {
    Id(o => o.Id);
    Map(o => o.Username);
    Map(o => o.EmailAddress);
    Map(o => o.DateOfBirth);
    Component(o => o.LegalName).ColumnPrefix("LegalName");
    // etc.
  }
}

public class PersonNameMap : ComponentMap<PersonName> // etc.
```

As shown above, I am trying to tie this all together with an AttributePropertyConvention. This works well for simple properties, e.g. EmailAddress will get a custom type of EncryptedColumnType.

But it is not working for properties which are complex types (e.g. LegalName) that are mapped via Components. What I want is to encrypt every property of LegalName because I decorated it with [Encrypted]. In other words, I want the UserRecord db table to have three encrypted 
name fields--given, middle, and family.

It seems that the AttributePropertyConvention is just not getting applied at all to the LegalName or any of its member properties. Perhaps I need to use another type of Convention to handle this case?

I know I can just decorate the individual properties within PersonName with [Encrypted], instead of decorating the [LegalName] property within UserRecord. I tested this and it works fine. I can fall back to this approach if necessary, but am interested in trying to get the approach outline above to work instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up, I did not find a way to directly implement what I described. I could see it being difficult or impossible to implement such a thing based on how attributes work in C#.

Instead, I just added the `[Encrypted]` attribute to each property of the `PersonName` class, and let those `PersonName` columns in the resulting database table always be encrypted. In the future, if I do need to map `PersonName` as a non-encrypted "component" of another entity, I could perhaps decorate the non-encrypted class with an attribute that *disables* encryption for all of its mapped columns/components, overriding any `[Encrypted]` attributes found in that class's property/component mappings.